# SAGA Upslope Area Calculation from Vector Point Layer resolves in no output and no error message

Tags: pyqgis, saga, hydrology

I'm using the SAGA Upslope Area algorithm within pyqgis, but i'm stranded, since my script doesn't create any output at all. I'm trying to use geometry from points in a vector point layer as input x and y in the saga algorithm, but it doesn't give me any error messages and i can't seem to find the problem. Can you see any problem with my script below?

```
##points=vector
##dtm=raster
##upslope_area=output raster

from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from processing import *

upslope_area = processing.getObject(upslope_area)
iterator_points = processing.getObject(points)
dtm = processing.getObject(dtm)

for feature in iterator_points.getFeatures():
    geometry = feature.geometry()
    point = geometry.asPoint()
    x_point = point[0]
    y_point = point[1]
    Processing.initialize()
    processing.runalg('saga:upslopearea', None,x_point,y_point,dtm,None,0,1.1,upslope_area)
```

Comment: Doesn't Upslope Area need a Grid instead of a Point file? I recommend getting the Tool working in the Desktop app, then working on the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have data to test with but made some dummy files and simplfied your code a little which runs and outputs temporary files. Couldn't confirm if the results were correct but it was just a test to see if any output files are generated:

```
##points=vector
##dtm=raster

iterator_points = processing.getObject(points)

for feature in iterator_points.getFeatures():
    geometry = feature.geometry()
    point = geometry.asPoint()
    x_point = point[0]
    y_point = point[1]
    processing.runandload('saga:upslopearea',None,x_point,y_point,dtm,None,0,1.1,None)
```

it should be like:

```
processing.runandload('saga:upslopearea',None,x_point,y_point,dtm,None,0,1,1,None)
```